# combine ko observables into a ko observable array

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I currently have two observables that I want to merge into an array to send to my backend application for processing, they are:

```
self.ElementData = ko.observable(localStorage.getItem('ElementDataWidget'));
self.scorecardIDLocalStorage = ko.observable(localStorage.getItem('scorecardId'));
```

The issue I have is my backend will only accept one parameter, not two. How would I merge these two? I have started with this code, but I am getting confused with it.

```
self.ElementData = ko.observable(localStorage.getItem('ElementDataWidget'));
self.scorecardIDLocalStorage = ko.observable(localStorage.getItem('scorecardId'));
self.LocalstorageData = ko.computed(function(){
    var tempStorage = [];

    ko.Utils.arrayForEach(self.ElementData(), function(item){
        tempStorage.push({
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Why does it have to be computable array? You have a function, that is invoked, which does the API call, right? At that point, just combine your two observables into an object that you'll send to your backend.

Comment: As long as i can get it as a combination i can use any method, Im pretty new to Knockout, could you show me how i should combine them @Yanchi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not test it but there were at least two things missing:

```
self.LocalstorageData = ko.computed(function(){
    var tempStorage = [];

    ko.Utils.arrayForEach(self.ElementData(), function(item){
        tempStorage.push({
        })
    })
    return tempStorage // <--- !!
}, this) // <--- !!
```